# Is it possible to transfer an entire Windows 7 installation to a new hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, thinkpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I transfer a Windows 7 installation to a new HDD?](https://superuser.com/questions/121326/how-do-i-transfer-a-windows-7-installation-to-a-new-hdd)
>   [How do you clone a Windows 7 installation?](https://superuser.com/questions/123372/how-do-you-clone-a-windows-7-installation)

I have a very well customized install of Windows 7, with tons of apps and configuration. I'm running it on a Lenovo Thinkapad X201 and I'm getting a new Thinkpad X220 with a solid state drive. How can I image the Windows 7 install on the X201 and simply move it over?

Comment: That question has no sufficient answer, although I agree it looks similar.

Comment: ClonzeZilla to teh rescues!

Comment: Did someone remove my comment?

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to look into the [Windows Automated Installation Kit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Automated_Installation_Kit), I believe this is the equivalent to using *SysPrep* in a Windows XP Environment. I have used the *SysPrep* option on Lenovo ThinkPads in the past with Windows XP in a *domain* environment without a hitch. This is the M$ way of doing it I believe; though you could *clone* the drive using [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/) if the drive in the new machine is identical in size.

One thing you may want to note though, seeing as you are going from an X2 **01** to an X2 **20**; is the hardware **exactly** the same, does the **X201** also contain an SSD?

If the answer to the last two questions is no, then you may run into some driver issues upon completion of the cloning process.

*Note: There are paid for solutions that also provide this ability such as Acronis*

Answer (score 0):

You can use CloneZilla LiveCD to make an exact copy of one hard drive over to another.