# Does the windows 8 recovery disk make a clean install on another drive in the same pc?

Tags: windows-8

If I make a [recovery disk on windows 8](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-create-windows-8-recovery-cd/) will it be able to fully restore my windows 8 installation if my hdd fails and I need to buy a new one?

Comment: James Hill pointed that link in this question http://superuser.com/questions/493529/if-i-upgrade-windows-7-to-8-in-one-drive-can-i-copy-the-installation-to-another and as I'm not very familiar with windows this is a good question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes. A recovery disk has the ability to restore your Windows 8 installation, but not your files. Just try to keep a copy of your Windows 8 key for when prompted in the recovery menu, and you should be safe.

In order to keep files and programs in Windows 8, you need to set up automatic hard drive backups via file history.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if it will create a fresh install on *another* drive, no, it will only recover a previous Windows 8 installation.