# How can I save my operating system and transfer it to a new SSD?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I transfer a Windows 7 installation to a new HDD?](https://superuser.com/questions/121326/how-do-i-transfer-a-windows-7-installation-to-a-new-hdd)

I recently purchased a Mushkim SSD to replace my failing hard drive of my H/P Dv6-12465dx laptop.

Physical installation of the SSD should be easy. I have my existing HD divided into five virtual drives, one of which contains the Windows 7 Operating System.

There were no back up disks when I purchased the machine originally.  How do I go about saving the Operating system and transferring it to the new SSD?

Answer (score 0):

Use DIXML [http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm] to backup your windows. There are tutorials available on how to use DIXML.
Also, if you can borrow the windows installation disc from your friend then it would be easier because the product key for your OS is available on the sticker on the underside of your laptop. No, this is not piracy because you paid for the OS and they did;t give you the CD. I recommend this over DIXML as it will be easier assuming you do not want to backup your data. :)

Comment: Don't forget to disable automatic defrag in Windows 7 once you boot from the ssd.

Comment: @Moab why is that?

Comment: defrag is not good for SSD's, a clean install of W7 on a ssd will disable it by default, but when you move an installation to an ssd [you need to do disable it manually](http://blog.tune-up.com/tips-and-tricks/four-steps-to-optimize-your-ssd/)